# How do I measure internal resistence of voltmeter without ammeter?

Tags: measurement, voltmeter, internal-resistance

I know how to do it with ammeter, but how can I find internal resistence without ammeter?

Comment: An ammeter is simply a combination of a resistor and a voltmeter.

Comment: If it is not ideally calibrated, you cannot do that without some other measurement device.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what type of meter - digital or analog - and provide a part number, if possible. Usually it is marked on them and is certainly in the specification or user manual.

Comment: ... or more commonly, a voltmeter is the combination of an ammeter and a resistor. Do you have an ohmmeter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5dZZx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. DC voltmeter impedance measurement technique.*

For a DC meter such as a typical digital multimeter you can try the scheme of Figure 1.

- Use a very stable reference voltage. (OK use a PP3 9 V battery.)
- Take a voltage reading from your reference voltage with the meter in question (Figure 1a).
- Use a precision reference resistor. (OK grab a 1M resistor out of your bag of resistors.)
- Take a second voltage reading from your reference (Figure 1b). If R1 is significant relative to the meter the reading will drop.

e.g. If the meter reading falls to half when using a 1M resistor then the resistor must have an input impedance of 1M.

The easiest way to do it is to keep adding or subtracting resistance until you get a reading of half of the battery voltage. That resistance is equal to that of the meter.

---

Update

> VM2/9V = (R1+Ri)/R1 Is this correct?

No. \$ \frac {meter \ voltage}{total \ voltage} = \frac {meter \ R}{total \ R} \$. So, 
\$ \frac {VM2}{9} = \frac {Ri}{R1 + Ri} \$.

Comment: You don't have to keep trying resistors.  As long as the resistor is reasonably close to the voltmeter resistance, a simple calculation using the voltage divider formula will yield a good value for the resistance.

Comment: Correct but I hadn't the energy to explain that to the OP. Add it as a separate answer if you want. You can copy my diagrams.

Comment: @Barry Can you write that formula?

Comment: @Ninalol: Why don't you write the formula in the question and we'll tell you if it's right. It will have three knows: VM1, VM2 and R1 and one unknown - Rmeter. It's just a ratio calculation.

Comment: VM2/9V = (R1+Ri)/R1 Is this correct?

Comment: See the update. Your math-fu isn't too good! Look at your formula: VM2 would be greater than the battery voltage.